# Add XMl attributes if not exist using Xpath Navigator

Tags: c#, xml, xpathnavigator

I want to add attributes only when it is not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Check out: http://egeveke.blogspot.com/2006/09/xpathnavigator-missing-setattribute.html

Basically you use MoveToAttribute, testing if it was successful.  If not, then it does not exist and you can create.  Remember to either start with a clone of you navigator, or move back to the parent when you are successful.

```
if (nav.MoveToAttribute())
{
  // exists
  nav.MoveToParent();
} 
else
{
  nav.CreateAttribute(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Insert XML Data using XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x8bxy86.aspx). Specifically the section `Inserting Attribute Nodes`

Comment: but it doesn't check attribute exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Use "**HasAttributes**" property on the Xpathnavigator object to check whether it has any attributes and then continue to do your operation. Hope this helps!!

Comment: I want to check for a particular attribute??/

Comment: Try using **GetAttribute** method and based on its return value, u can add the new attribute, if it does not exist.

Comment: you can also try using MoveToFirstAttribute() and then get its name and value like: 

` if (xPathNav.MoveToFirstAttribute())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xPathNav.Name + "=" + xPathNav.Value);        
        }`